# How to add context to recompose's withHandlers()?

Tags: reactjs, recompose

`recompose` has this function called [`withHandlers`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withhandlers) that lets you define an event handler while keeping your component pure.

e.g. if you had something like this inside you `render()` method:

```
<TextInput value={value} onChange={ev => this.handleChange(ev.target.value)} />
```

it wouldn't be pure because every time your component renders, it'd by passing a different `onChange` function to your `TextInput` component.

This is great, but how can this be extended to support arrays of inputs? Or otherwise provide auxiliary data?

e.g. taking their example and extending it a bit:

```
const enhance = compose(
    withState('values', 'updateValue', ''),
    withHandlers({
        onChange: props => inputName => event => {
            props.updateValue(inputName, event.target.value)
        },
        onSubmit: props => event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            submitForm(props.value)
        }
    })
)

const Form = enhance(({ value, onChange, onSubmit, inputs }) =>
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <label>Value
            {inputs.map(input => (
                <TextInput value={value} onChange={onChange(input)} />    
            ))}
        </label>
    </form>
)
```

I've fudged the details a bit, but pretend `inputs` comes in as an array of input names. e.g. `["firstName","lastName"]` would render two textboxes, one for each.

I want to store the values for each of these in my state, but I don't want to define separate updater functions for each. Thus I need to attach some metadata to the `onChange={...}` prop so that I know which field I'm updating in my state.

How can I do that?

In my example I wrote `onChange(input)` and added an extra 'level' to the `withHandlers.onChange` function to accept the extra argument, but `withHandlers` doesn't actually work that way. Is there some way to do this -- i.e., ensure that each `TextInput` receives the same function instance every time `<Form>` is rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a typical case where you need to define the change handle directly inside your TextInput component.
You'd need to pass updateValue function as a prop to TextInput components.

Comment: Oh..and pass the input name as a separate prop into `TextInput`? I guess that might work, but that requires modifying every input component to be able to handle such scenarios.

Comment: Great example! Thank you for that.